# jquery click and preventDefault error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to prevent a Jquery onclick function to scroll the page to the top.
I found out that preventDefault() would fix this problem but I can't get it to work.

Here's the website with the code:
http://www.femartins.com.br/novo/galeria.html

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.carouselObj').click(function(evt){
        var index = $('.carouselObj').index(this);
        $('.galcontent').eq(index).siblings('.galcontent').fadeOut(500,function() {
            $('.galcontent').eq(index).fadeIn(500);
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
    });

});
```

Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: you let the event complete before you tried to prevent it.

Comment: Kevin, I already tried to move it to the top of the code and other places. :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `evt.preventDefault();` in the event handler. Not in the complete callback function of `fadeOut`

```
$('.carouselObj').click(function (evt) {

    //Use here
    evt.preventDefault();


    var index = $('.carouselObj').index(this);
    $('.galcontent').eq(index).siblings('.galcontent').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('.galcontent').eq(index).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. You can check the website source code and you will see that I did exactly what you told me.

Comment: @user1541940, You have updated source. What do you exactly want, when you click on that

Comment: I just want to switch the images which is working fine but I don't wanna the screen going to the top every-time

Answer (score 0):

Figure the problem wasn't on click but the way the html was built.
I added a div with the same height as the content and the problem was solved!

Thanks